# so simple ask about while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I am beginner in python and I have two exercises. The first one runs smoothy, no problem. But thesecond one does not run... Why? What is the difference between them?

First:

```
x=0
while x<10:
    print 'x is currently:', x
    print 'x is still less than 10, adding to x'
    x+=1

    if x==3:
        print 'Hey x equals 3!'
    else:
        print 'continuing...'
        continue
```

second one:

```
x=0
while x<2:
    print 'may be!!'
    x+=1

    if 2<x<10:
        print "the number is:", x

    else:
        print 'not yet!!'
        continue
```

Comment: Superficially, the code looks fine. I think you need to give more context and description of the problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your second loop executes without error; it *does* run.  It is not designed to duplicate the output of the first loop.  We need you to describe your problem.

Comment: Unnecessary use of the `continue` word BTW. It will still go on to the next iteration

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if 2<x<10:
```

X never be more than 2. Because at the beginning you give 0 to X. And you say;

```
"while x<2:"
```

When x is bigger than 2 or equal, it quits from while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I infer that your problem is not printing out `the number is: 3`, and perhaps anything after that.

The problem is in your loop control sequence:

```
while x<2:               # Exit the loop once x reaches 2
    print 'may be!!'
    x+=1                 # x is no longer the value you tested;
                         # is that really what you want?
    if 2<x<10:
        print "the number is:", x
```

The `if` statement will never be `True`; when `x` is 0 or 1 at the `while`, you increment it to 1 or 2, and the condition is still `False`.  On the next iteration, the `while` condition forces you to exit the loop.

BTW, a `continue` at the bottom of a loop is useless; the loop will continue naturally.

Comment: Thank you for every helps here!!! I solve my problem. First of all, I tried to get all data for every number up to 10. But as you said my loop was breaking and get that I want.

Answer (score 0):

Play around with values and variables and loop formats to get it better, learning is achieved by trying stuff out for yourself.
Your code sets `x=1`, then prints 'may be' and increments variable and then skips the `if`, going into `else` and prints 'not yet'. With `x=1`, 'may be ' is printed one more time, then setting `x=2`, it skips the `if` again as the condition accepts only `x` more than 2 not equal. Then `print` 'not yet' inside `else`, checks the loop and stops it as x is no longer less than 2, but equal.